# Can I reverse a Counter into a list of lists without multiples?

Tags: python, sorting, counter

Using the [Collection Counter](https://pymotw.com/2/collections/counter.html),

```
l1 = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'e']
l2 = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'b','d']

from collections import Counter

c1 = Counter(l1)
c2 = Counter(l2)

# Intersection 
c1 & c2

>>> Counter({'b': 3, 'c': 2, 'a': 1})
```

What idiom could distribute Collections Counter into a list of lists where each multiple appears only once in each list?

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'],['b', 'c'],['b']]
```

Comment: Does the order in the final lists matter or just the contents?

Comment: The Collections Counter returns a `dict`, so i believe we're out of luck on that point. Nevertheless, that is also a good problem--take two lists with multiples and return a list of lists each list without multiples.

Answer (score 6):

Don't know if you were looking for a one-liner, but here is a one-liner:

**Code:**

```
[sorted(y for y in z if y is not None) 
       for z in it.izip_longest(*[[k] * l for k, l in c.items()])]
```

**How?**

Two key things here:

1. `[k] * l` gives a list of the counter keys which is counter values long
2. `izip_longest()` will put the lists togther and pad fill with none for the shorter lists

**Test Code:**

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter({'b': 3, 'c': 2, 'a': 1})

import itertools as it
print([sorted(y for y in z if y is not None) 
       for z in it.izip_longest(*[[k] * l for k, l in c.items()])])
```

**Results:**

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['b', 'c'], ['b']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import itertools

the_dict = {'b': 3, 'c': 2, 'a': 1}

the_frequencies  = [[a]*b for a, b in the_dict.items()]

the_list = itertools.izip_longest(the_frequencies)

the_final = map(list, list(itertools.izip_longest(*the_frequencies)))

print [[i for i in b if i != None] for b in the_final]
```

This solution uses itertools to zip the lists contained in the_frequencies that are created by multiplying a list of the key multiplied its corresponding value. izip then forms a list with the rows of the elements in the_frequencies, storing None if the count of the current iteration is greater than the length of any list in the list of lists.

Comment: Note, in Python 3.5 `izip_longest()` is now `zip_longest()`